# Spring Boot Refuses to Start, problem with AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I created a project using the Spring Starter, but it won't run. It gives me an error message that looks like this:

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$AutoConfiguredAnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:133)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanNameGenerator;)V

The method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/miguelmunoz/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.10.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/config/AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource: file:/Users/miguelmunoz/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.10.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar
    org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport: file:/Users/miguelmunoz/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.10.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I have checked in a minimum reproducible test case at https://github.com/SwingGuy1024/dummy.artifact-MRTC

My pom file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>dummy.artifact</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>dummy.artifact</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <springfox-version>2.9.2</springfox-version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>--> <!--I tried both. Neither version worked.-->
    </parent>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!--Handles serialization/deserialization of new Java Date/Time classes-->
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Neumann-SR4</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**Addendum:** As far as I can tell, I only have a single version of AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource, which is in the spring-data-commons repository. As I understand it, the versions of spring-data should be determined by the dependencyManagement section of my pom.xml file, where I specify the spring-data-releasetrain. I've tried several different values for that, but none of them work. The one specified here, `Neumann-SR4`, is the most recent one. But it doesn't give me the most recent version of spring-data-commons.

**Addendum 2:** *Changes suggested by gtiwari333, below*

I made the following changes and checked them into the GitHub repository. And I still have a problem.

1. I moved classes RFC3339DateFormat and Swagger2SpringBoot to the dummy package and adjusted the parameters to the @ComponentScan annotation.
2. I renamed CTwo to CTwoDto, and created a new CTwo class in a new `dummy.entity` package.
3. The repository now uses to the new CTwo entity class
4. I bumped the Spring-Boot version up to 2.3.3.RELEASE. (2.3.4 gives me a compiler error in a swagger-generated file — it can't find `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`)
5. I removed three dependencies: `jackson-datatype-jsr310`, `validation-api`, and `jackson-annotations`
6. I remove the dependencyManagement section from the pom file.
7. I fiddled with the logging levels.

(These changes take me to the original bug that led me to create this MRTC.)

I still get an error message, although a different one.

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.java:126)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata.introspect(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;

The method's class, org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/miguelmunoz/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/miguelmunoz/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.core.type.AnnotationMetadata
```

Once again, I only have a single version of the class in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems to your code. One or all of these may be causing the problems that you are facing.

1. You do not have `dummy.invoker.Swagger2SpringBoot` at root package `dummy`. Spring Boot recommends you to put the @SpringBootApplication class at root package so that it scans all the components and repositories without having you to scan manually.
   If you must put this class inside the `dummy.invoker` package, then please do the following so that it scans the Repository class
   `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"dummy.repository"})`

Also,

`@EntityScan(basePackages = {"dummy.model"})` to scan the CTwo entity

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

2. CTwo is not a proper Entity class. But you are using it on CTwoRepository. Make it a Entity class with a @Id

```
@Entity
public class CTwo   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id = null;
```

**Extra notes:**

3. There's no need to override the springframework.data version. Remove this from pom.xml. Spring `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` pulls the correct version that works well together with the given spring boot version.

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Neumann-SR4</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

4. No need to put @Repository and @Component at repository class

```
@Repository
@Component
public interface CTwoRepository ...
```

5. No need to override the `jackson-annotations` version. In fact you don't need to put this dependency at all.  Also, no need to define the jackson-datatype-jsr310, validation-api. They are pulled transitively.

---

See this patch for the changes that you need to do before you can run your app:

Also, why are you using the old spring boot version? Please update that to latest.

```
Index: src/main/java/dummy/repository/CTwoRepository.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- src/main/java/dummy/repository/CTwoRepository.java  (revision 27a2e1045263f79fd3c490fce14b2640b12fa3a4)
+++ src/main/java/dummy/repository/CTwoRepository.java  (date 1601681768001)
@@ -12,7 +12,5 @@
  *
  * @author Miguel Mu\u00f1oz
  */
-@Repository
-@Component
 public interface CTwoRepository extends JpaRepository<CTwo, Integer> {
 }
Index: src/main/java/dummy/model/CTwo.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- src/main/java/dummy/model/CTwo.java (revision 27a2e1045263f79fd3c490fce14b2640b12fa3a4)
+++ src/main/java/dummy/model/CTwo.java (date 1601681492814)
@@ -7,18 +7,22 @@
 import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
 import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
 import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
+
+import javax.persistence.*;
 import javax.validation.Valid;
 import javax.validation.constraints.*;
 
 /**
  * CTwo
  */
-@Validated
-@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2020-10-01T10:23:27.051Z[GMT]")
+//@Validated
+//@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.SpringCodegen", date = "2020-10-01T10:23:27.051Z[GMT]")
 @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
-
+@Entity
 public class CTwo   {
   @JsonProperty("id")
+  @Id
+  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id = null;
 
   @JsonProperty("name")
Index: pom.xml
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- pom.xml (revision 27a2e1045263f79fd3c490fce14b2640b12fa3a4)
+++ pom.xml (date 1601682065794)
@@ -15,8 +15,7 @@
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
-       <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
-       <!--<version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>--> <!--I tried both. Neither version worked.-->
+       <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
@@ -74,55 +73,5 @@
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
 
-       <!--<dependency>-->
-       <!--    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>-->
-       <!--    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>-->
-       <!--    <version>2.3.2</version>-->
-       <!--</dependency>-->
-       
-       <!--&lt;!&ndash; Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module &ndash;&gt;-->
-       <!--<dependency>-->
-       <!--    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>-->
-       <!--    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>-->
-       <!--    <version>2.3.2</version>-->
-       <!--</dependency>-->
-
-       <dependency>
-           <!--Handles serialization/deserialization of new Java Date/Time classes-->
-           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
-           <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
-       </dependency>
-       <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
-       <dependency>
-           <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
-           <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
-       </dependency>
-       <dependency>
-           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
-           <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
-           <version>2.10.1</version>
-       </dependency>
-
-       <!--&lt;!&ndash;Actuator&ndash;&gt;-->
-       <!--<dependency>-->
-       <!--    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
-       <!--    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-docs</artifactId>-->
-       <!--    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>-->
-       <!--</dependency>-->
-       <!--<dependency>-->
-       <!--    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
-       <!--    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>-->
-       <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
-   <dependencyManagement>
-       <dependencies>
-           <dependency>
-               <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
-               <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
-               <version>Neumann-SR4</version>
-               <scope>import</scope>
-               <type>pom</type>
-           </dependency>
-       </dependencies>
-   </dependencyManagement>
 </project>
Index: src/main/java/dummy/invoker/Swagger2SpringBoot.java
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
--- src/main/java/dummy/invoker/Swagger2SpringBoot.java (revision 27a2e1045263f79fd3c490fce14b2640b12fa3a4)
+++ src/main/java/dummy/invoker/Swagger2SpringBoot.java (date 1601681394614)
@@ -4,13 +4,17 @@
 import org.springframework.boot.ExitCodeGenerator;
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
+import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
 
+import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
 import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
 
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableSwagger2
-@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "dummy.invoker", "dummy.api" , "dummy.config", "dummy.repository"})
+@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"dummy.repository"})
+@EntityScan(basePackages = {"dummy.model"})
+@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "dummy.invoker", "dummy.api" , "dummy.config" })
 public class Swagger2SpringBoot implements CommandLineRunner {
 
     @Override
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. But this just brings be back to the original bug that led me to create this (very flawed) MRTC. Having fixed everything you suggested, and checked it in, I still have a problem, which I put in the 2nd addendum to my original post.

Comment: Why are you still overriding the spring data version?

Comment: Just delete your <dependencyManagement> section

Comment: The pom file in the description is out of date. I have deleted the dependency management section, and I am no longer overriding the spring data version. You can look in the repository for the new pom.xml file. Or, if you want, I could add it to the description.

Comment: Just look at the diff I posted. Its working fine ever for sb 2.3.4

Comment: I looked at the diff, but I didn't use it. Instead, I made the changes I described, which cover all the same issues. I'm not sure how you got it to even compile with sb 2.3.4. I get a compiler error in the DummyTwoController.

Comment: CTwo does now have `@Entity` and `@Id` annotations.

Comment: The problem turned to be my IDE. When I tried it from the command line, it ran just fine. I still can't get it to run from my IDE, but that's a separate problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I should add that the central problem was that I didn't put the main class in the main package. I put it in a sub-package.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a conflict between spring libs - almost identical problem is described here:

[how to make spring data lib compatiable in spring boot 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564275/how-to-make-spring-data-lib-compatiable-in-spring-boot-2-x)

Tip: When trying to debug this sort of error, start with a search for a portion of the exact error message you're getting that seems relevant (copy paste it). Try to narrow it down to something generic if nothing shows up immediately and you'll find similar problems.

Also worth noting there's a message at the end of the output that describes what you need to do to fix the problem:

```
Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource
```

This suggests there are more than two compatible versions of "some class". If you search specifically for the problematic class mentioned, you'll likely find a lot more people with the exact same problem + their solutions.

Comment: I've already read that answer. It told me to stick to the starters, but I was already doing that. I had read other answers too, and they didn't help either. And as far as I can tell, I only have one version of AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.

I have found that sometimes, Spring Boot's error messages don't point to the actual problem. In this case, with only one version of that class, their Action leads me nowhere.