# DynamoDB: Filed to configure a DataSource. 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How to correctly use DynamoDB with Spring?

I tried to follow many tutorials but always got the same error.

For example my realization of [baeldung tutorial][1]:

- application-properties:

```xml
#AWS-creds
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
amazon.aws.accesskey=
amazon.aws.secretkey=

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

- configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories
        (basePackages = "com.hrzc.demo.repository")
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.endpoint}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBEndpoint;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accesskey}")
    private String amazonAWSAccessKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretkey}")
    private String amazonAWSSecretKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB
                = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(amazonAWSCredentials());

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint)) {
            amazonDynamoDB.setEndpoint(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint);
        }

        return amazonDynamoDB;
    }

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials amazonAWSCredentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(
                amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey);
    }
}
```

- entity:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Url")
public class Url {

    private int id;

    private String longUrl;

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    public String getLongUrl() {
        return longUrl;
    }

    public void setLongUrl(String longUrl) {
        this.longUrl = longUrl;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

- repository:

```java
@EnableScan
public interface UrlRepository extends CrudRepository<Url, Long> {
}
```

The `pom` file does not equal the `pom` from the tutorial, but I hope this is not the reason, since I can't start the project with `dependencyManagement` - the error sounds like `An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist.` - and I found the suggestion to remove the `spring-boot-data overriding` [here][2].

- pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hrzc</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>linkshrtnr</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.64</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- I created the `Url` table via `aws-cli`:

```
> aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name Url

{
    "Table": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "id",
                "AttributeType": "N"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "longUrl",
                "AttributeType": "S"
            }
        ],
        "TableName": "Url",
        "KeySchema": [
            {
                "AttributeName": "id",
                "KeyType": "HASH"
            },
            {
                "AttributeName": "longUrl",
                "KeyType": "RANGE"
            }
        ],
        "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "CreationDateTime": "2022-09-25T22:40:39.385000+03:00",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
        },
        "TableSizeBytes": 0,
        "ItemCount": 0,
        "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:393546347656:table/Url",
        "TableId": "33f8baed-4d6c-4787-845d-1df7d0749cea"
    }
}
```

So, how to use dynamoDB correctly?

```
  [1]: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-dynamodb
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171751/spring-boot-refuses-to-start-problem-with-abstractrepositoryconfigurationsource
```

Comment: Please share the full stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

check your application properties file

```
#for mysql
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#for postgres
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

my properties file is with other config is like

```
spring.datasource.name=localSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=   
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

sometimes also check to update maven dependency by updating the maven (sts4/ eclipse)